# Linux, sudo env does not have environment variable while root user has

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, sudo, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have RHEL 7 and I want to set environment variable for sudo.

I have run `sudo su` in order toswitch to root user and added `export` to its `.bashrc` file. Then I have reloaded them with `source`.

Now when I run `env` in `root` mode it has environment variable. However, when I exit and run `sudo env` it does not.

Why this is happening?

Comment: Why would it? You're tell it to just run env. There isn't going to be an interactive bash login that would trigger the bashrc file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo` runs programs in its own, limited environment (see the ENVIRONMENT section of the manual `man sudo`). It does not implicitly use `bash` to run programs, so `~/.bashrc` is not run, though you can invoke it explicitly:

```
sudo bash --rcfile=~root/.bashrc -c ProgramAndParameters
```

You can set an environment variable in the run string:

```
sudo variable=value ProgramAndParameters
```

You can use an alias or function to do either of these by default.

You can alternatively add an environment file to `/etc/sudoers` (see `man sudoers` for more information).

Answer (score -1):

sudoers entry as below

```
%DBTEAM     ALL = (oracle) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

*DBTEAM --> Group Name*

*oracle  --> oracle user name*

switch to Target user Without environment variable
`sudo -s -u oracle`

switch to Target user With environment variable
`sudo -i -u oracle`

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please make sure your answer directly answers the question as stated. Your answer does not answer the question and does not relate to what the question is asking.